# Chirality of anti-bodies

Tags: antibody, chirality

Do anti-bodies in the blood stream present chirality?

I am interested in this question from a mathematical and physical point of view. A person allowed to travel through a fourth spatial dimension is able to come back in this world as her mirror image. The heart will be on the right side now etc.

If the anti-bodies are chiral dependent they won't recognize the old viruses, so the person will die soon.

Comment: If you have a question about the chirality of proteins please do some research before asking here, as all posters are expected to do. If you are still unclear after your research, explain why, but please do not dilute it with fictional anecdotes about people returning from a fourth dimension. It is not necessary.

Comment: @dimachaerus - please discontinue the harassment of other users. Thanks.

Comment: @user1136 - answers in comments are not encouraged. Comments are reserved for inquiries to OP in terms of clarification of the post. If you think you know an answer, either write up as a full-blown answer (including sources), or refrain from commenting at all. Given your interesting comments, I suggest turning i into an answers. Just add some sources and expand on the key issues. I've deleted the comment. If you need the comment for further processing, and you can't retrieve it, just ping me here. Thanks.

Comment: "so the person will die soon" except, perhaps, that the pathogens can't act on the reverse-chirality of the person.  On the other hand, the person will probably not find any nutrients that they can digest, as sugars, proteins, etc are chiral, and so will starve.

Answer (score 3):

Antibodies are proteins and proteins are made up of L-amino acids, which have at least 1 chiral centre. Therefore proteins contain chiral centres. So yes antibodies have chirality.

Comment: @dimachaerus If the part of the virus/bacteria that the antibody recognizes is not chiral then it doesn't matter. However most likely it will be chiral then yes it probably wont be recognized anymore.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you add resources to your answer, and expand a little bit on the key issues? One-liners aren't encouraged. +1 for the answer though, it seems to make a lot of sense.